# ErrorHandling in SpringXD

Tags: java, redis, spring-xd

I have configured Redis as MessageBus for my spring-xd setup. When my stream fails, the data is pushed to Error Queues. I'm trying to read them back and push them back to destination queues. But I don't see the my Sink modules receiving data. Can some help me understand where I'm going wrong.

Code Snippet.

```
public RedisTemplate<String, byte[]> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
  final RedisTemplate<String, byte[]> template = new RedisTemplate<String, byte[]>();
  template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
  template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
  template.setEnableDefaultSerializer(false);
  return template;
}

List<String> listOfKeys = new ArrayList<>();
Set<byte[]> keys = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().keys("ERRORS*".getBytes());
for (byte[] data : keys) {
  listOfKeys.add(new String(data, 0, data.length));
}
for (String errorQueue : listOfKeys) {
    String destinationQueue = errorQueue.replace("ERRORS:", EMPTY_STRING);
    Long size = redisTemplate.opsForList().size(errorQueue);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        byte[] errorEvt = redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPop(errorQueue);
        redisTemplate.opsForList().leftPush(destinationQueue, errorEvt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at your code says it should work ok; I suggest you run `redis-cli` and then enter `monitor` to watch the redis traffic.

**EDIT**

To answer your comment below - it depends on your content type. If it's simple text, it's relatively easy:

```
"\xff\x01\x0bcontentType\x00\x00\x00\x0c\"text/plain\"2016-05-20 10:11:07"
```

The first part are headers, you can decode that with XD's `EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter`.

If your payload is a java object, it is serialized by the bus using kryo.

Comment: Thank You @Gary. I found the issue. My destination queue is missing prefix "queue.". It has to be destinationQueue = "queue." + errorQueue.replace("ERRORS:", EMPTY_STRING); Can you please help me how to convert errorEvt  (byte[] errorEvt = redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPop(errorQueue);) into my actual payload, i would like to log the msg for testing purpose.